# Change the php composer uses

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, command-line-interface, composer-php

I am using to start laravel. Therefore I have installed it with composer and somehow it doesn't work after installation i dont see the public folder.. I tried the same steps on my raspberry and there it is installed as it should be; I think the reason that the installation on my macbook doesn't work is that laravel/composer listens to the native php build from my macbook..(5.3.5) ( I am using the one I installed with homebrew php 5.5.3) I have tried many things but with no result. is there a way to delete composer and install it again? ( because i installed the homebrew php a while after installing composer )

Although ,, if I do composer show I get this

```
      composer show
  platform:
    ext-bcmath     0         The bcmath PHP extension
    ext-bz2        0         The bz2 PHP extension
    ext-calendar   0         The calendar PHP extension
    ext-ctype      0         The ctype PHP extension
    ext-curl       0         The curl PHP extension
    ext-date       5.5.3     The date PHP extension
    ext-dba        0         The dba PHP extension
    ext-dom        20031129  The dom PHP extension
    ext-ereg       0         The ereg PHP extension
    ext-exif       0         The exif PHP extension
    ext-fileinfo   1.0.5-dev The fileinfo PHP extension
    ext-filter     0.11.0    The filter PHP extension
    ext-ftp        0         The ftp PHP extension
    ext-gd         0         The gd PHP extension
    ext-gettext    0         The gettext PHP extension
    ext-hash       1.0       The hash PHP extension
    ext-iconv      0         The iconv PHP extension
    ext-json       1.2.1     The json PHP extension
    ext-ldap       0         The ldap PHP extension
    ext-libxml     0         The libxml PHP extension
    ext-mbstring   0         The mbstring PHP extension
    ext-mcrypt     0         The mcrypt PHP extension
    ext-mhash      0         The mhash PHP extension
    ext-mysql      1.0       The mysql PHP extension
    ext-mysqli     0.1       The mysqli PHP extension
    ext-mysqlnd    0         The mysqlnd PHP extension
    ext-odbc       1.0       The odbc PHP extension
    ext-openssl    0         The openssl PHP extension
    ext-pcntl      0         The pcntl PHP extension
    ext-pcre       0         The pcre PHP extension
    ext-PDO        1.0.4dev  The PDO PHP extension
    ext-pdo_mysql  1.0.2     The pdo_mysql PHP extension
    ext-PDO_ODBC   1.0.1     The PDO_ODBC PHP extension
    ext-pdo_sqlite 1.0.1     The pdo_sqlite PHP extension
    ext-Phar       2.0.1     The Phar PHP extension
    ext-posix      0         The posix PHP extension
    ext-readline   5.5.3     The readline PHP extension
    ext-Reflection 0         The Reflection PHP extension
    ext-session    0         The session PHP extension
    ext-shmop      0         The shmop PHP extension
    ext-SimpleXML  0.1       The SimpleXML PHP extension
    ext-snmp       0.1       The snmp PHP extension
    ext-soap       0         The soap PHP extension
    ext-sockets    0         The sockets PHP extension
    ext-SPL        0.2       The SPL PHP extension
    ext-sqlite3    0.7-dev   The sqlite3 PHP extension
    ext-sysvmsg    0         The sysvmsg PHP extension
    ext-sysvsem    0         The sysvsem PHP extension
    ext-sysvshm    0         The sysvshm PHP extension
    ext-tokenizer  0.1       The tokenizer PHP extension
    ext-wddx       0         The wddx PHP extension
    ext-xml        0         The xml PHP extension
    ext-xmlreader  0.1       The xmlreader PHP extension
    ext-xmlrpc     0.51      The xmlrpc PHP extension
    ext-xmlwriter  0.1       The xmlwriter PHP extension
    ext-xsl        0.1       The xsl PHP extension
    ext-zip        1.11.0    The zip PHP extension
    ext-zlib       2.0       The zlib PHP extension
    lib-curl       7.24.0    The curl PHP library
    lib-iconv      1.11      The iconv PHP library
    lib-libxml     2.7.8     The libxml PHP library
    lib-openssl    0.9.8.18  The openssl PHP library
    lib-pcre       8.32      The pcre PHP library
    lib-xsl        1.1.26    The xsl PHP library
    php            5.5.3     The PHP interpreter
    php-64bit      5.5.3     The PHP interpreter (64bit)
```

Is there a way to do one of this things?

Answer (score 0):

Run composer using your new php:

```
php composer <command>
```

That will work if your right PHP is on path, but since composer is using the old one it may not be, so:

```
/usr/bin/php composer <command>
```

or something like

```
/usr/src/php55/bin/php /usr/bin/composer <command>
```

To find the path of composer you can do

```
type composer
```

And it should show you something like:

```
composer is hashed (/usr/bin/composer)
```

If it works for you, then you just need to create an alias

```
alias composer='/usr/src/php55/bin/php /usr/bin/composer'
```

And then just run it as you would do normally:

```
composer <command>
```

For this to work you need know or find the correct path of your PHP 5.5, so you can use the command locate or find to do this. In this case using the `type` command won't work, because your PHP 5.3 is in the path and it will show you its path.

You can download and install composer again

```
cd /tmp
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/composer
```

But it looks like it will not make any differentes for you, because it's just a matter of using the right php to run composer:

Comment: I have done all this steps and everything seems correct but the problem is that I still can't install laravel framework correctly

Comment: How are you installing Laravel and which errors are you receiving?